# SQL Case Statement trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, switch-statement

im not the best when it comes to SQL still learning the ropes.
I have a Stored procedure in my SQL server manager 2008.

```
USE [ShaftData]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetSalesBuyers]    Script Date: 03/23/2012  08:13:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSalesBuyers] 
@Cdisc varchar(255),
@bcs varchar(255), 
@From date, 
@Too date
AS
SELECT i.Acct,
   i.Name, 
   i.Document, 
   i.Part, 
   i.Qty, 
   i.Unit, 
   dbo.NEWPareto.Pareto, 
   i.pg,
   dbo.MyPgTable.PgName,
   i.[DateTime],
   i.BinSeqNo,
   i.cdisc,
   i.bcs

FROM   
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT dbo.iHeads.acct,
                            dbo.iHeads.name,
                            dbo.iLines.Document,
                            dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            dbo.iLines.Qty,
                            dbo.iLines.unit,
                            dbo.iHeads.[DateTime], 
                            dbo.iLines.BinSeqNo, 
                            dbo.Customer.cdisc,
                            dbo.Customer.Bcs
                     FROM Autopart.dbo.iheads INNER JOIN   Autopart.dbo.iLines ON 
                     Autopart.dbo.Iheads.document = autopart.dbo.iLines.document
                     INNER JOIN Autopart.dbo.Customer ON Autopart.dbo.iheads.acct 
                     = Autopart.dbo.customer.keycode
                     GROUP By dbo.iHeads.acct,
                            dbo.iHeads.name,
                            dbo.iLines.Document,
                            dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            dbo.iLines.Qty,
                            dbo.iLines.unit,
                            dbo.iHeads.[DateTime],
                            dbo.iLines.BinSeqNo,
                            dbo.Customer.cdisc,
                            dbo.Customer.bcs
                      ') i
left JOIN
dbo.NEWPareto
ON 
i.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.NEWPareto.Part 
left JOIN
dbo.MyPgTable 
ON  
 i.pg collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.MyPgTable.[pGroup]

WHERE
 (i.[DateTime] BETWEEN @From AND @Too) 
 AND i.cdisc = @Cdisc 
 AND i.bcs != @bcs
 AND i.pg != '60'
 AND i.pg != '61'
 AND i.pg != '62'

 GROUP BY i.Acct,
   i.Name, 
   i.Document, 
   i.Part, 
   i.Qty, 
   i.Unit, 
   dbo.NEWPareto.Pareto, 
   i.pg,
   dbo.MyPgTable.PgName, 
   i.[DateTime],
   i.BinSeqNo,
   i.cdisc,
   i.bcs
```

What I need is a condition in the Where clause. particular this row "AND i.bcs != @bcs".

What happens is IF i pass an Empty string to my param i want this row to exist and run in the where clause.

Else IF i dont pass anything (null), i need the row to not exist(not run).

I have played around but all im getting is red lines everywhere when i attempt to create.

Does anyone have an idea? am i close in my methodology? can it be done? or is there a easy mode way that im over looking.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional parameters are constructed like this:

```
WHERE (@bcs is null OR i.bcs != @bcs)
```

If you send null every row is selected; if you send anything else, only non-matching rows are selected. You shouldn't worry about performance because Sql Server is very good with constant expressions, and if it evaluates to one it will be suppressed.

```
USE [ShaftData]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetSalesBuyers]    Script Date: 03/23/2012  08:13:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSalesBuyers] 
@Cdisc varchar(255),
@bcs varchar(255), 
@From date, 
@Too date
AS
SELECT i.Acct,
   i.Name, 
   i.Document, 
   i.Part, 
   i.Qty, 
   i.Unit, 
   dbo.NEWPareto.Pareto, 
   i.pg,
   dbo.MyPgTable.PgName,
   i.[DateTime],
   i.BinSeqNo,
   i.cdisc,
   i.bcs

FROM   
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT dbo.iHeads.acct,
                            dbo.iHeads.name,
                            dbo.iLines.Document,
                            dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            dbo.iLines.Qty,
                            dbo.iLines.unit,
                            dbo.iHeads.[DateTime], 
                            dbo.iLines.BinSeqNo, 
                            dbo.Customer.cdisc,
                            dbo.Customer.Bcs
                     FROM Autopart.dbo.iheads INNER JOIN   Autopart.dbo.iLines ON 
                     Autopart.dbo.Iheads.document = autopart.dbo.iLines.document
                     INNER JOIN Autopart.dbo.Customer ON Autopart.dbo.iheads.acct 
                     = Autopart.dbo.customer.keycode
                     GROUP By dbo.iHeads.acct,
                            dbo.iHeads.name,
                            dbo.iLines.Document,
                            dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            dbo.iLines.Qty,
                            dbo.iLines.unit,
                            dbo.iHeads.[DateTime],
                            dbo.iLines.BinSeqNo,
                            dbo.Customer.cdisc,
                            dbo.Customer.bcs
                      ') i
left JOIN
dbo.NEWPareto
ON 
i.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.NEWPareto.Part 
left JOIN
dbo.MyPgTable 
ON  
 i.pg collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.MyPgTable.[pGroup]

WHERE
 (i.[DateTime] BETWEEN @From AND @Too) 
 AND i.cdisc = @Cdisc 
 AND (@bcs is null OR i.bcs != @bcs)
 AND i.pg != '60'
 AND i.pg != '61'
 AND i.pg != '62'

 GROUP BY i.Acct,
   i.Name, 
   i.Document, 
   i.Part, 
   i.Qty, 
   i.Unit, 
   dbo.NEWPareto.Pareto, 
   i.pg,
   dbo.MyPgTable.PgName, 
   i.[DateTime],
   i.BinSeqNo,
   i.cdisc,
   i.bcs
```

Comment: thanks for the post, could you apply that to my code, ive had a go but im getting red underlines telling me what ive done is wrong

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you are getting errors please post first one.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i know of that you can do that (exactly what you want is to use dynamic sql), that being said, its not pretty. You chuck your whole proc in a string variable then build it up as needed. then execute it in the end. I'll update this post with a sample in a bit.

look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688161/tsql-writing-into-a-temporary-table-from-dynamic-sql) as to how the syntax looks normally.

Don't judge me I don't code like this normally

but this is the part you're looking for

```
 IF (ISNULL(@bcs,0) <> 0)
       SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND i.bcs != '+@bcs + CHAR(13)
```

Your updated proc.

```
USE [ShaftData]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetSalesBuyers]    Script Date: 03/23/2012  08:13:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSalesBuyers] 
@Cdisc varchar(255),
@bcs varchar(255), 
@From date, 
@Too date
AS

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = ' SELECT i.Acct, i.Name, i.Document, i.Part, i.Qty, i.Unit, dbo.NEWPareto.Pareto, i.pg,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   dbo.MyPgTable.PgName,i.[DateTime],i.BinSeqNo,i.cdisc,i.bcs' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM   ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, ''SELECT dbo.iHeads.acct, dbo.iHeads.name,dbo.iLines.Document,dbo.iLines.Part, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iLines.Pg,dbo.iLines.Qty,dbo.iLines.unit,dbo.iHeads.[DateTime], dbo.iLines.BinSeqNo, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.Customer.cdisc,dbo.Customer.Bcs ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                     FROM Autopart.dbo.iheads INNER JOIN   Autopart.dbo.iLines ON ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                     Autopart.dbo.Iheads.document = autopart.dbo.iLines.document' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                     INNER JOIN Autopart.dbo.Customer ON Autopart.dbo.iheads.acct ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                     = Autopart.dbo.customer.keycode' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                     GROUP By dbo.iHeads.acct,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iHeads.name,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iLines.Document,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iLines.Part,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iLines.Pg,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iLines.Qty,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iLines.unit,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iHeads.[DateTime],' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.iLines.BinSeqNo,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.Customer.cdisc,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                            dbo.Customer.bcs' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '                      '') i' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'left JOIN' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'dbo.NEWPareto' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'ON ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'i.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.NEWPareto.Part ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'left JOIN' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'dbo.MyPgTable ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'ON  ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' i.pg collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.MyPgTable.[pGroup]' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' (i.[DateTime] BETWEEN ''+@From+'' AND ''+@Too+'') ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND i.cdisc = '+ @Cdisc  + CHAR(13)


IF (ISNULL(@bcs,0) <> 0)
   SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND i.bcs != '+@bcs + CHAR(13)


SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND i.pg != ''60''' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND i.pg != ''61''' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND i.pg != ''62''' + CHAR(13)

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' GROUP BY i.Acct,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.Name, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.Document, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.Part, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.Qty, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.Unit, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   dbo.NEWPareto.Pareto, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.pg,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   dbo.MyPgTable.PgName, ' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.[DateTime],' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.BinSeqNo,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.cdisc,' + CHAR(13)
SET @SQL = @SQL + '   i.bcs' + CHAR(13)
```

EXEC(@SQL)

Comment: ouch, well i simple way is to duplicate the procedure without that one line, then have the condition exist in my code to call iether one. But as we all know duplicating something is never a good way.

Comment: ok, i prefer @Nikola Markovinović's answer. didn't actually know you could use optional params in a where clause. seems iv'e been schooled too...

Comment: also the CHAR(13) is a new line character, i used to work at a company with 1000 legacy sql procs, all like that :|, and it helper with reading the proc inside SQL profiler

Comment: holy hell in a hen basket that made my eyes bleed. ill have to take a good look at that, never seen sql statement like it before hehe, then again as i said im pretty new to sql

Comment: if you can avoid it at all cost, i think it was the way people used to do it before they knew any better... 

I'll see if i can whip up a sample with @Nikola Markovinović's advice.