# SQL Server 2008 - #tmp table throws error when run within an exec command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TSQL Writing into a Temporary Table from Dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688161/tsql-writing-into-a-temporary-table-from-dynamic-sql)

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ServicesStats1](@PERIOD VARCHAR(30) )

 AS
 BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result SETs FROM
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


 DELETE FROM servicesstats1;
 DECLARE @QUERY  NVARCHAR(MAX);

 DECLARE @mainTable VARCHAR(50)

 SET @mainTable = '[ServicesStats' + @PERIOD + ']';



 SET @QUERY = 'INSERT INTO servicesstats1(Department,StudentUsers) 
 SELECT department,COUNT(*) FROM ' +  @mainTable + 
 'GROUP BY department';

 EXEC(@QUERY); -- runs okay!


 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..[##tmp5]') is not null 
BEGIN 
    drop table [##tmp5] 
END

 SET @QUERY = ' SELECT studentid
 INTO [##tmp5]
 FROM ' + @mainTable + '
 GROUP BY studentid
 having COUNT(*)=1; select * from [##tmp5];';
 PRINT @QUERY;


 EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY;

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..[#tmp3]') is not null 
BEGIN 
    drop table [#tmp3] 
END

 SELECT S.department,COUNT(*) AS No INTO #TMP3 --  ONLY THIS SERVICE 
 FROM servicesstats_0511_0412 s, #TMP5 T    -- this is not being replaced yet by the @mainTable
 WHERE S.STUDENTID = T.STUDENTID
 GROUP BY S.department
```

Error :

> *Invalid object name '#TMP5'.*

The problem is temporary table `#tmp5`, now if I were to run this it would work but it's not dynamic.

```
SELECT studentid
INTO [#tmp5]
FROM tableName
GROUP BY studentid
having COUNT(*)=1;
```

Basically I'm doing this because of the dynamic table name. But `#tmp` is throwing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a local temporary table, which only exists within the scope of your dynamic sql, so you could reference it as follows without error:

```
SET @QUERY = ' SELECT studentid
INTO [#tmp5]
FROM ' + @mainTable + '
GROUP BY studentid
having COUNT(*)=1; 
SELECT * 
FROM [#tmp]';

EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY;
```

However, when you try and access it outside of the scope of your dynamic sql you can no more access it that you could from another window in SSMS. You'll need to use a global temporary table, then you can access it:

```
SET @QUERY = ' SELECT studentid
INTO [##tmp5]
FROM ' + @mainTable + '
GROUP BY studentid
having COUNT(*)=1;';

EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY;

SELECT  *
FROM    [##Tmp5];
```

Just be aware of possible issues in a multi user environment.

Comment: Hi Gareth, Thanks for the input. However when I tried it (it's part of a stored procedure) it still throws the same error, even when I added an extra # sign.

Comment: The error is almost certainly not coming from when you are inserting the data into the table, it will be coming from later on in the procedure where you are referencing the table. Can you post more of your procedure?

Comment: Sure will do. The error gets thrown on the next line following the exec though.

Comment: I really can't see where the error is occurring. [This SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46451/2) shows that there should be no problem creating a temp table in dynamic SQL and referencing it later. Let me have a think...

Comment: I'm replacing everything in my code with double hashes will let you know :)