# Inserting into a temporary table from an Execute command

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, execute, temporary

I need to insert data from a select statement into a temporary table using the execute command.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#x') is not null
drop table #x

Create Table #x(aaa nvarchar(max))

declare @query2 nvarchar(max)
set @query2 = 'SELECT [aaa] from IMP_TEMP'

INSERT #x
SELECT [aaa] from IMP_TEMP -- THIS WORKS
SELECT *from #x

INSERT #x
exec @query2 -- THIS DOES NOT WORKS, WHY?
SELECT *from #x
```

Comment: The temp table is not in the same scope as that used to execute the dynamic sql. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688161/tsql-writing-into-a-temporary-table-from-dynamic-sql / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688161/tsql-writing-into-a-temporary-table-from-dynamic-sql

Comment: @AlexK: Those questions are about a temporary table in an inner scope that the OP wants to read in an outer scope.  This question is about the opposite, which is no problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need parenthesis around `@query2` variable. `EXEC` command is to execute stored procedure, while `EXEC()` function is for executing dynamic sql taken as parameter.

```
INSERT #x
exec (@query2)
SELECT *from #x
```

[Reading material](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/13/sql-server-difference-between-exec-and-execute-vs-exec-use-execexecute-for-sp-always/)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Alex K comments, a local temporary table is visible inside all inner scopes within a connection.  The following snippet runs fine:

```
create table #tbl (id int)
exec ('select * from #tbl')
```

You can also use `insert ... exec` with temporary tables:

```
create table #tbl (id int)
insert #tbl values (3), (1), (4)
insert #tbl exec ('select id from #tbl')
```

If this doesn't work for you, please post the exact error.  One likely culprit is that `insert ... exec` demands that the column definition of the table and the query match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT #x
exec @query2 -- THIS DOES NOT WORKS, WHY?
SELECT *from #x
```

Have you tried using the correct synthax:

```
INSERT #x
exec (@query2) 
SELECT *from #x
```

Comment: Nenad Zivkovic marked correct as more information about the exec function was documented